# Join + count on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i just want to know how much prods are linked with the id from the table emp and i can't find that. I want to get all the emp fields + field called totalProducts with the number of the linked rows with the id so, how can I do it? I'm trying this and not working:

```
 select emp.*, 
        COUNT(prod.*) AS totalProducts 
 from emp_fin emp 
      JOIN product2 prod on emp.id = prod.id_emp group by emp.id;
```

Getting error like: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) ...

Thank you all!

Comment: I think you just want `count(*)`.  You don't use aliases with `count(*)`.

Comment: but does count(*) know that I mean the prod table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want count all the prod records, select the id_emp (or another notnull field) of toe prod table to count them.

```
SELECT
    emp.*,
    COUNT(prod.id_emp) AS totalProducts
FROM emp_fin emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN product2 prod
    on emp.id= prod.id_emp
group by emp.id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use aliases with `count(*)`:

```
select emp.*, COUNT(*) AS totalProducts
from emp_fin emp JOIN
     product2 prod
     on emp.id = prod.id_emp
group by emp.id;
```

If you wanted to include emps with no products, use `left join` and do the count like this:

```
select emp.*, count(prod.id_emp) AS totalProducts
from emp_fin emp left join
     product2 prod
     on emp.id = prod.id_emp
group by emp.id;
```